# IIS subfolder in different website

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

www.mycompany.tld <-- our company website (based on Sitefinity/ASP.NET)
www.mycompany.tld/blog <-- our company blog (based on Wordpress/PHP)

Does somebody know how to do this?

I don't want to redirect the user to a different URL, e.g. blog.mycompany.tld, because then I would loose all the PageRank-flow which will hopefully come to our blog.

Comment: I've voted to close this as "belongs on serverfault" as this is something you'd handle with IIS configuration, particularly as you've not asked *anything* to do with code in your question. You're much more likely to get an answer over there (http://www.serverfault.com) :-)

Comment: @Rob, sorry for that, you're right of course. However, the answer I got here actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried converting the folder `/blog` into a new Virtual Application, with it's own AppPool, that runs the php application?

In regards to the SEO issue, yes, you will lose **some** of the page rank, but with suitable cross-linking and content you will still maintain some "link juice" as our SEO consultants call it.

Comment: Thank you Ben! This actually did the trick. For all others, trying to do the same: you have to deal with web.config inheritance - take a look at the "inheritInChildApplications" - attribute!